# How can I get predicted values in SVM using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, cross-validation

I am trying to get a prediction column matrix in MATLAB but I don't quite know how to go about coding it. My current code is -

```
load DataWorkspace.mat
groups = ismember(Num,'Yes');
k=10;

%# number of cross-validation folds:
%# If you have 50 samples, divide them into 10 groups of 5 samples each,
%# then train with 9 groups (45 samples) and test with 1 group (5 samples).
%# This is repeated ten times, with each group used exactly once as a test set.
%# Finally the 10 results from the folds are averaged to produce a single 
%# performance estimation.

cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', groups, k);
cp = classperf(groups);
for i = 1:k                               
    testIdx = (cvFolds == i);               
    trainIdx = ~testIdx;                   
    svmModel = svmtrain(Data(trainIdx,:), groups(trainIdx), ...
                 'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'Method','SMO', ...
                 'Kernel_Function','rbf');

    pred = svmclassify(svmModel, Data(testIdx,:), 'Showplot',false);

    %# evaluate and update performance object
    cp = classperf(cp, pred, testIdx);
end
cp.CorrectRate
cp.CountingMatrix
```

The issue is that it's actually calculating the accuracy 11 times in total - 10 times for each fold and one final time as an average. But if I take the individual predictions of each fold and print *pred* for each loop, the accuracy understandable reduces greatly.

However, I need a column matrix of the predicted values for each row of the data. Any ideas on how I can go about modifying the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of cross-validation is get an unbiased estimate of the performance of a classifier.

Once that done, you usually just train a model over the entire data. This model will be used to predict future instances.

So just do:

```
svmModel = svmtrain(Data, groups, ...);
pred = svmclassify(svmModel, otherData, ...);
```